# MCP23S17 - do I have to use both Chip Select and Hardware Addressing?

Tags: multiplexer, expander, mcp23s17

I've used MCP23S17 before. 6 of it and I just used Chip Select. Hardware address pins all 0.

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001952C.pdf

In datasheet, hardware addressing can be used to connect 8 of it in a bus. No problem.

Now, I have another project that will require 12 of MCP23S17. I plan to use Chip Select again.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

If you set HAEN = 0 the hardware addressing bits are ignored and you can do addressing purely by the chip select.

You will need to fully decode the chip selects so that each device of the 12 has a unique chip select.

If HAEN = 1 the hardware addressing bits are taken in account in addition to the chip select. In that case you would not need to fully decode the chip selects although you will need at least 2 as the hardware address can only uniquely decode 1 of 8.

See section 3.5.6 on page 20.

Comment: thank you! i have plenty of MCU GPIO so will use 12 of it for CS. not really a fan of hardware addressing.